# What is forcing my system to look for MySQL in "/opt/local/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, osx-lion

I have been trying to get a ruby on rails app going on my machine for a little while now for a project I need to work on for work. The issue is, my system must be setting the default location of MySQL somewhere because every time I start the rails webserver (webrick) and run localhost:3000, I get the following error.

**"Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"**

I have deleted the installed version of mysql and removed all folders. I reinstalled mysql using BREW. I now have a running mysql instance. The output of "which mysql" prints "/usr/local/bin/mysql" which is actually a sim link to "/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.14/bin/mysql".

Does anyone know what might be forcing my rails apps to look for mysql in "/opt/local/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"

NOTE: I deleted my current my.cnf because it was messing up the brew version of mysql I currently have running, so I know that is has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Check the ruby config. That's a client-side error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/opt/local` is the default location for MacPorts-installed packages. Chances are you installed `rails` and or `MySQL` via MacPorts.  Try:

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/port installed
```

to see what is installed.

Comment: Ok, you are correct, I did have mysql4 installed from macports. I just uninstalled it and I still have the BREW version of mysql installed and running. But now I am getting the following error when trying to run the app or just "rake db:create"... "uninitialized constant Mysql::Error". Any ideas?

Comment: Now that you have cleaned things up, you may need to reinstall the brew packages that depend on MySQL. If you have other MacPorts ports installed, you should uninstall them first.  Don't mix package managers!  Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: Thanks for you help. All is well after uninstalling all macports installed, reinstalling mysql with BREW, and reinstalling mysql gem.